# How to apply asynchronous fix to loops?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, callback

I'm stuck on some code in an `index.js` file that get the home page (*called* `index.hbs`), which references to a file called `product-seeder.js` (*containing a loop that goes through all products listed in an array*) and every time the loop goes through a listed product, it renders an output on the home page.

The server rendered way more outputs than I had listed products. I know that this is because javascript is asynchronous, but when I used the code from the tutorial(that is supposed to fix the asynchronous problem) and tried to load the server, it just kept loading and won't stop.

I have no clue to why it's doing that. Did I do something wrong? Thanks, help is much appreciated.

My `index.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Product = require('../models/product');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Product.find(function(err, docs) {
    res.render('shop/index', {title: 'Shopping Cart', products: docs});
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

My `product-seeder.js`:

```
var Product = require('../models/product');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/shopping', { useNewUrlParser: true });

var products = [
    new Product({
        imagePath: 'image.png',
        title: 'PD 1',
        description: 'Product 1',
        price: 1
    }),
    new Product({
        imagePath: 'image.png',
        title: 'PD 2',
        description: 'Product 2',
        price: 2
    }),
    new Product({
        imagePath: 'image.png',
        title: 'PD 3',
        description: 'Product 3',
        price: 3
    })
];

var done = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    products[i].save(function() {
        done++;
        if (done === products.length) {
            exit();
        }
    });
}

function exit() {
    mongoose.disconnect();
}
```

My index.hbs:

```
{{# each products }}
    Output text
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that in the rendered page there are more products than expected.

On your database, how many products are saved? The same amount of the rendered? If yes, the issue happens when you save your products.

You can rewrite the "save logic" as following

```
const products = [/* .. things here .. */]

// This save one after another
async function save() {
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        await products[i].save(); // this can generate an eslint warning/error
    }
}

// This save all products basically together, if products.length is > 10 can be a bad idea
async function save() {
    return Promise.all(products.map(prod => prod.save()));
}

save().then(() => mongoose.disconnect());
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work... The server just kept loading like before.

Comment: On your database, how many products are saved (after the execution of `product-seeder.js`)? The same amount of the rendered?

Comment: I checked my mongodb database via the command 'db.products.find()' and there are less products  than outputs rendered. In fact, the data wasn't even updating. For some reason the products it displayed does not match my current 'products' array.

Comment: If `product-seeder.js` has to save 3 items and with `db.products.find()` you retrieve 3 items, it's ok. If there are 3 items in mongo but a different number in the rendered view, you should check the `/models/product` moodel. Maybe is supposed to be used like `Product.find(query, callback);` instead of `Product.find(callback);` ??

Comment: I finally solved the problem! Turns out I just had to remove all products from the database, run the seeder, and insert `{ useNewUrlParser: true }` into `mongoose.connect()`.